# Virtualmin-Webmin Inaccessible when cloudflare is ON

Tags: cloudflare, webmin, virtualmin

The problem that i have is that the only way i can get to the login page (in a subdomain) is when i have cloudflare OFF for that record, the moment i turn on Cloudflare, it never show me nothing, after a while only shows an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error. ¿Can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

solved by myself. For other facing the same problem: The problem is the 10000 port, Cloudflare in the free plan only allow the following ports:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-

You have to change it in: Webmin -> Webmin configuration -> Ports and Addresses - change port, and restart Webmin; then enable Cloudflare, and you are ready to go.

Comment: This worked (I used port 8443 and rebooted my VPS).

Answer (score 0):

Wow this fixed my issue! All my systems are on cloudflare, but none of the linux forums addressed this, they all mentioned editing host files and opening firewall ports.

Comment: Please do not add a comment as an answer